# Wrong extra options in the combo box in Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I make a custom module for mu site on Drupal 7. There should be several combo boxes on a page, so I make a form with several 'select's. The options of the selects are taken from the database.

Now there are three boxes: 'speaker', 'year', 'booknumber'. 'Speaker' and 'booknumber' work perfect, but 'year' makes all wrong. There are hundreds of options which there should not be, along with 6 elements which are got from my database. As far as I can see, wrong elements appear in 'options_years' array, because 'query_year' contains only those 6 elements.

What I have tried to do:

1. Change variable names in case they conflict with something.
2. Change DB column name 'year' in case it conflicts with something.
3. Clean cache of my site.
4. Uninstall and install my module after making some changes.
5. Google it (well, maybe I was choosing wrong English words to describe my problem).

Please, could you give me some advice or directions? I just don't know where to dig :(

Here is my code:

```
 function corpus_retrieve_speaker() {
 $query_speaker = db_select('corpus_text', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('speaker'))
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('speaker', 'ASC') //Most recent first.
    ->execute(); 
  return $query_speaker;
}

function corpus_retrieve_year() {
 $query_year = db_select('corpus_text', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('year'))
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('year', 'ASC') //Most recent first.
    ->execute(); 
  return $query_year;
}

function corpus_retrieve_booknumber() {
 $query_booknumber = db_select('corpus_text', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('booknumber'))
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('booknumber', 'ASC') //Most recent first.
    ->execute(); 
  return $query_booknumber;
}

function corpus_form($form, &$form_state) {
    //form speaker combo
    $speakers = corpus_retrieve_speaker(); 
    $options_speaker = array();
    $i_s = 0;
    foreach ($speakers as $unit1) {
        $options_speaker[$i_s] = t($unit1->speaker);
        $i_s = $i_s + 1;
    }
    $form['corpus_search_speaker'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Speaker'),
        '#empty_option' => t('Choose a speaker'),
        '#options' => $options_speaker,
        );
    //form year combo
    $years = corpus_retrieve_year();
    $options_years = array();
    $i_y = 0;
    foreach ($years as $unit2) {
        $options_years[$i_y] = t($unit2->year);
        $i_y = $i_y + 1;
    }
    $form['corpus_search_year'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Year'),
        '#empty_option' => t('Choose a year'),
        '#options' => $options_years,
        );      

    //form booknumber combo
    $booknumbers = corpus_retrieve_booknumber();
    $options_booknumber = array();
    $i_b = 0;
    foreach ($booknumbers as $unit3) {
        $options_booknumbers[$i_b] = t($unit3->booknumber);
        $i_b = $i_b + 1;
    }

    $form['corpus_search_booknumber'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t("Book number"),
        '#empty_option' => t('Choose a book number'),
        '#options' => $options_booknumbers,
        );

    $form['submit_params'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Search'),
    );


    return $form; 

}
```

Here is HTML of select which works good:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-corpus-search-booknumber">
<label for="edit-corpus-search-booknumber">Book number </label>
<select id="edit-corpus-search-booknumber" name="corpus_search_booknumber" class="form-select">
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose a book number</option>
<option value="0">350</option>
<option value="1">350 (1185)</option>
<option value="2">643</option>
<option value="3">660</option>
<option value="4">732</option>
<option value="5">732 (398)</option>
<option value="6">741</option>
<option value="7">808</option></select>
</div>
```

Here is a piece of HTML of select whuch doesn't work

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-corpus-search-year">
<label for="edit-corpus-search-year">Год </label>
<select id="edit-corpus-search-year" name="corpus_search_year" class="form-select">
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose a year</option>
<optgroup label="0"><optgroup label="ru"><optgroup label="">
<option value="Public files">Общие файлы</option>
<option value="Public local files served by the webserver.">Открытый — передачей файлов управляет веб-сервер</option>
<option value="Temporary files">Временные файлы</option>
<option value="Temporary local files for upload and previews.">Временные локальные файлы для загрузки и просмотра.</option>
<option value="Long">Полностью</option>
<option value="Medium">Средн.</option>
<option value="Short">Кратко</option>
<option value="done">выполнено</option>
<!-->Cut a lot of other wrong options<-->
<optgroup label="Long month name"><option value="January">января</option>
<option value="November">ноября</option>
<option value="December">декабря</option></optgroup>
<optgroup label="Font weight"><option value="Strong">Жирный</option></optgroup></optgroup></optgroup>
<!-->these are right options<-->
<option value="1">1958</option>
<option value="2">1962</option><option value="3">1967</option>
<option value="4">1972</option><option value="5">1983</option>
<option value="6">1985</option></select>
```

As far I see, lots of wrong options are taken from Drupal language files (Russian translation).

Comment: The problem is solved. I thoughtlessly used function t() because it was in the example, without knowing what t() does. The problem was in "t($unit2->year)"